# React Native - Fetch API Proper Error Handling

Tags: javascript, react-native, rxjs, observable

Im fairly new to React Native and additionally have reached 7 years of experience without learning proper error handling on the front end. I have been writing both front and backend for this particular application and have run into a situation I need clarity on.

I built a basic RBAC layer on the backend that does various checks before hitting the db endpoints. In this issue RBAC checks to see if the user is an admin; if the user isn't it returns a 401 status seen below:

```
rbac.check(role, type, {
    user: user,
    [identifier]: resourceId
  }, (err, result) => {
    if (!result) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'not authorized to access'
      })
    } else {
      return next();
    }
  }
);
```

To the best of my knowledge from reading articles this is the proper approach (could be wrong). The problem occurs on my frontend which is a React Native application using the Fetch API. I have a thunk that calls a service method which calls a generic http service method. I have wrapped the fetch api in an observable seen below:

```
// Thunk Code 
const _getOrganizations = (organizations) => {
  return {
    type: Types.TYPES_ORGANIZATIONS_SET,
    payload: organizations
  };
};

export const getOrganizations = (userId) => {
  return dispatch => {
    return OrganizationService.getAll(userId)
      .map(
        _data => {
          if (!_data['success'] && !_data['organizations']) {
            _data['organizations'] = [];
          }

          dispatch(_getOrganizations(_data['organizations']));
          return _data;
        }, _error => { return _error; }
      )
  };
};

// Service method:
getAll(userId) {
  return Http.$get(Constants.ENDPOINT_USER, userId, Constants.POSTFIX_ORGANIZATIONS);
}

// Http Service
$get(endpoint, id, postfix, auxId) {
  let _postfix = (typeof postfix === 'undefined' || postfix === null) ? '' : postfix;
  let _auxId = (typeof auxId === 'undefined' || auxId === null) ? '' : '/' + auxId;

  return Observable.defer(() => {
    return Observable.fromPromise(
      fetch(this.apiUrl + endpoint + id + _postfix + _auxId, {
        method: 'get',
        headers: this._headers()
      })
      .then(this._checkStatus)
      .then(res => res.json()));
    }
  );
}
```

As you can see the promise has a checkStatus method in the chain. I added this because it is what I have seen in all the examples of how to use the fetch api. My checkStatus method is as follows:

```
/**
 * Error Handling
 */
_checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return response;
  } else {
    let error = new Error(response.statusText);
    error.response = response;
    throw error;
  }
}
```

When the 401 is returned from the backend the else statement is ran throwing an error, which in the React Native realm throws up a red error screen to the user. This is obviously not something I want happening.

I basically lack the knowledge at this point to know what is the best practice for dealing with this kind of issue, so despite the fact that I can come up with various ways to deal with this, it doesn't mean I am doing what is best practice.

***Things I have done or considered:***

1. In the check status method I simply removed the throw error line and returned the response.

This makes little sense to me since this status check is generic and is supposed to handle many types of scenarios that can occur. It just so happens with an RBAC response I really don't care since the data was never really requested on the server.

2. I have considered adding more conditions to check for 401 and returning the response in this scenario.

That really doesn't solve the problem with the red screen as the same thing will happen with any error, for example a 500. Possibly part of the problem is my code and I am not dealing with the errors correctly.

Yes I know using Observables was not a sensible thing to do. I did this at first coming from an Angular world and thought it would be great to have. I learned as I went along that using redux nullifies most of the benefits of using observable in network request. I plan to strip out the code later but cannot do this right now.

Any assist and advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well any error conditions in your fetch API can be handled using a catch clause. In a catch clause you get access to the error and you can handle it however you want. Also is there any reason you are throwing the error ? Seems like bad practice since that possibly will cause crashes on a production app ( hence the red screen ).

Comment: I actually just pasted that code from an example awhile back when I first learned about Fetch. It was almost a year ago and now the app is almost done and I am trying to clean up stuff like this. I believe you kind of gave me the answer to my problem by pointing it out as the issue. Thanks.